# Login from mobile app and send authenticate infomation to webpage

Tags: c#, android, get, html

Im trying to make an app which sends authenticate information to a webpage.
Here is what i have created for app to send information:

```
String eventCoin = Util.getInstance().getEnhanceModel().getEventCoin();
if (eventCoin == null || eventCoin.equals("")){
 Toast.makeText(context, "Can't get link. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 return;
}

AccountModel accountModel = Util.getInstance().getAccount();

String strAuthenAccount = String.format("%d|%s|%s", accountModel.getAccountId(),
  accountModel.getAccount(), accountModel.getAccessToken());

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhh");
Date date = new Date();

String signKey = strAuthenAccount + "social)3@0!5" + dateFormat.format(date);
signKey = HashUtil.md5(signKey);

String link = String.format(
  eventCoin+"?autheninfo=%s&sign=%s",
  strAuthenAccount, signKey);

ShowWapView showWapView = new ShowWapView(context);
showWapView.show(link);
```

So I send an "autheninfo" and a "sign" to webpage.
On webpage, how can i receive "autheninfo"? I tried this way but it doesn't work

```
var authenInfo = Request.Params["authenInfo"] ?? string.Empty;
var sign = Request.Params["sign"] ?? string.Empty;
```

What should I do now to get authenInfo?

Comment: Your `autheninfo` and `authenInfo` are different, it's just a typo, right?

Comment: thanks, that's right, `autheninfo` and `authenInfo` are different.

Comment: you probably need to urlencode the valud of strAuthenAccount

Comment: njzk2: Can you explain me more?